# Grab page in chunks

Tags: c#

I am developing an application which needs to grab a web page and then parse it. I need to know is there any way to grab the page in chunks. I mean page could be divided and downloaded in parallel chunks and at the end I could get single a page. So that time can be saved.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 1.1 supports the `Range` header that allows you to download a resource in chunks. This is probably what you want. The HttpWebRequest object offers the AddRange method that allows you to do this.